# remote search form in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement a trivial asynchronous search form that would display the search results on the same page using AJAX. My code is below. The search results are rendered using a partial view. When the form is submitted I recreate an array of results and expect it to be displayed on the page. But this is not happening, the page does not get updated. I have been looking at rails for a day now, and I think it is trivial but I need help.

route:

```
match 'search' => 'search#index'
```

controller:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @results = params[:search] ? ['test0', 'test1', 'test2'] : []
  end
end
```

view `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => :get, :remote => true do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
<div id="results">
  <%= render :partial => 'results' %>
</div>
```

partial view `_results.html.erb`:

```
<ul>
  <% @results.each do |result| %>
    <li>
      <%= result %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed one more view corresponding to the view with the form: `index.js.erb`

```
$('#results').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'results') %>");
```

Answer (score -1):

You used ternary operator:

```
@results = params[:search] ? ['test0', 'test1', 'test2'] : []
```

It's syntax is:

```
If Condition is true ? Then value X : Otherwise value Y
```

but this is not a condition: `@results = params[:search]`, it's just assignment. You need to provide a condition,expression to return `true` or `false`, if `true` your `@result` will have `['test0', 'test1', 'test2']`, if false it will be empty.

Example about ternary operator:

```
irb(main):182:0> name = "akonsu"
=> "akonsu"
irb(main):183:0> name == "akonsu" ? "Hello akonsu" : "Who are you?" 
=> "Hello akonsu"
```

Comment: Actually, he's using the ternary operator in a correct, but potentially confusing way. `params[:search]` is in fact an expression that is being implicitly cast to true (object present) or false (nil). The idea is that he's just mocking up a search by saying that when the param `search` is present in any manner, assign an array full of test strings to the results, otherwise assign an empty array.